# OverflowError in a for loop

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I'm working on [problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) of Project Euler using Python, but I can't seem to solve the problem without running into the following error: "OverflowError: range() result has too many items"

I'm wondering if there's a way to increase the allowed range? My code looks as follows:

```
target = 600851475143
largest_prime_factor = 1

#find largest prime factor of target
for possible_factor in range(2,(target/2)+1):
    if target % possible_factor == 0:
        is_prime = True
        for i in range(2,(possible_factor/2)+1):
            if possible_factor % i == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime:
            largest_prime_factor = possible_factor

print largest_prime_factor
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run into *limitations* of your computer or language while trying to solve a *puzzle* problem, or if it takes too long, it is an indication that probably there exists a better *way* (read: algorithm) to solve the problem. In your case, you do not need to loop to `target / 2 + 1` (though that is a good educated upper bound). You only need to go as far as `ceil(sqrt(target))`.

---

And, as a sidenote, you can overcome this limitation by using [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange), which will create a generator, instead of `range` for Python 2, which creates a list. In Python 3, `range` will return a [`sequence type`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) instead of a `list` by default.

Thanks to [@Fernando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5119090/fernando-matsumoto) for the clarification in the comments.

Comment: Typo in the last sentence. It should be `range` instead of `xrange`. Also, in Python 3, `range` is a [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range), rather than a function that returns a generator.